# Why does my permission check (Discordia bot) always return false?

Tags: lua, discord

The problem is on line 10. No matter what role or permission I have I always get my "You don't have admin or the role required (test message)" message from my bot. I thought it was because I was using "and" instead of "or" but that only fixed a previous problem (which was I would always be approved to use the command no matter what permission or if I had admin). Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Edit: I needed to use "and" instead of "or", and I didn't make sure to take admin off of my alternate account I was using to test this.

```
client:on("messageCreate", function(message)
        if message.author.bot == true then 
        return end

    local author = message.guild:getMember(message.author.id)
    local authorRole = message.guild:getMember(message.member)

    if message.content == prefix.."Permissions" then
        for i, v in ipairs(roleswithpermission) do
            if not author:hasPermission("administrator") or not authorRole:hasRole(v) then
                message.channel:send("You don't have admin or the role required (test message)")
            elseif author:hasPermission("administrator") or authorRole:hasRole(v) then
                message.channel:send("This is a test message (means the permission check worked and you have permission)")
            end
        end 
    end     
end)
```

Comment: Change `or` to `and` in line#10

Comment: I feel stupid lol. You're answer is correct. Turns out when I was using "and" instead of "or" I still had the admin role on my alternate account, so that's why it always approved. Thanks for somehow making me realize this lol